# Drupal 7 finding all site pages

Tags: php, drupal

Is there a way to get an array of all pages in a Drupal 7 site? (Not only node pages, but also views, webforms etc..)

Answer (score 0):

The `menu-links` table consist of all the links (admin as well as non admin) you could access.

You could use the function [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7)() to get them in array.

```
function MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  //$items is the array you are looking for.
  // printing the array
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r ($items);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

Be sure to replace the `MODULE` from the function name with the name of you module.
Might as well use [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) to print the `$items` array using `dpm($items);`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I will try this asap and let you know if it worked out.

Comment: @user762805 were you successful in implementing this hook?